# Android Alarm notification on particular date and time and app should be active

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager

I need to know step by step process to do notification

requirement:
user will register for an event and then they will notification before one day at 9 am and before half an hour.

- even if app is not active they should get notification.

Comment: There are tones of example on SO or just in google.

Comment: We would love to help you out but we need to see what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really simple task you can either use Alarm-manager to set to go off on that day which will fire a notification to your app.
https://www.sitepoint.com/scheduling-background-tasks-android/

A better approach would be to use a job scheduler http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Comment: Even if the link answers the question, It is always advisable to place the real/significant answer in the answer section. Link can broken at any time and it is not helpful for the future users/generation.